# Passing bash commands with parameters to a function

Tags: bash, shell

I have a very large shell script which provides a standardised process & logic wrapper around a number of daily administrative tasks for a specific application.

To ease debugging and maintenance I tried to create a RUN function which can switch between screen or logfile output depending on flag:

```
##
 # Executes the command, which is passed as $1
 # If debug mode is enabled, dump full execution output to screen
 ##
function RUN()
{
  if $debug; then
    # output to screen
    $*
  else
    # Suppress screen output, but capture all output in logs
    $* &>> $logs
  fi
}
```

With the idea that by invoking my script with a debug flag I could get full output to screen:

```
./script -d PARAMETERS
```

Unfortunately I've had very mixed success with this RUN function in my script.  Some of my functions work fine, and others do not.
The script worked perfectly before I added the RUN function wrapper, but I really need the added functionality it offers (when it works).

Here are some examples of use cases of the RUN function in my script:

```
# Example 1, set vars for a loop
local PARAM_LIST=$(RUN "BINARY PARAM1 PARAM2 -PARAM3")
for p in ${PARAM_LIST[@]}; do
  # Stuff
done

# Example 2, basic execution with pipes
$(RUN "BINARY PARAM1 PARAM2 -PARAM3 | awk {'{ print $2,$1 }'} | xargs -n1 BINARY PARAM1 PARAM4")

# Example 3, conditional execution
for i in ${!ARRAY[@]}; do
  if [[ ! $(RUN "BINARY PARAM1 PARAM2 $i") ]]; then
    # do stuff
  fi
done
```

I'm fairly sure the bash syntax is where I'm going wrong, but am having trouble tracking down the root cause.

Can anyone help point out what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: What exactly goes wrong? Can you give a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) showing the problem? I see a couple of possible issues, having to do with `$*` causing weird parsing (use `"$@"`, including the quotes, and don't add spurious quotes to the arguments to it), and `&>> $logs` sending all output to the log *only* (thus suppressing all normal output). But I don't know if these are causing what you're seeing. Also: [shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net) may spot other problems.

Comment: You defined your function to have (buggy) `execve(2)` semantics where you specify a program argument list, but you (buggily) invoke it as if it had `system(3)` semantics where you specify a shell command. It looks like the easiest fix is to switch to `system(3)` throughout and use `eval "$1"` instead of `$*`. You'll have to make sure to escape e.g. the `$`s in your awk commands.

Comment: Similar to @thatotherguy, I'd suggest switching from `$*` to `"${@}"` (note the quotes).

Comment: Really, don't do this.  If you want to redirect output of all commands to a file, use `exec` near the beginning of the script.  (eg, `exec >> "$logs" 2>&1`)

Comment: Thanks guys, using exec and quoting the params in RUN helped resolve some of the issues but removing RUN entirely and redirecting all command output with exec based on the value of $debug simplified the code greatly which makes it easier to read & maintain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It fails because your function expects multiple command arguments (like `sudo`, `env`, `xargs`, `find`, etc), but you instead pass it a single string with a shell command (as if for `su`, `ssh`, `sh -c`).

You have your function expect a shell command instead:

```
function RUN()
{
  if $debug; then
    echo "Executing: $1" >&2
    # output to screen
    eval "$1"
  else
    # Suppress screen output, but capture all output in logs
    eval "$1" &>> $logs
  fi
}
```

You will have to correctly escape all commands:

```
# Fails because $2 and $1 are not being escaped:
RUN "env | awk -F= '{ print $2, $1 }'"

# Succeeds because command is correctly escaped:
RUN "env | awk -F= '{ print \$2, \$1 }'"
```

A different option to consider is just writing your entire script in debug mode, and then optionally squash output, so that you don't have to add any additional escaping:

```
# Save stdout&stderr in case we need it
exec 5>&1 6>&2

# Optionally squash output
if ! "${debug:false}"
then
  exec &>> "$logs"
fi

# This only shows output if debug is on
BINARY PARAM1 PARAM2 -PARAM3 | awk '{ print $2,$1 }' | xargs -n1 BINARY PARAM1 PARAM4

# This always writes to stderr, whether debug is enabled or not
echo "Done" >&6
```